# How to decode a byte arrray in python using cv2

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

**Hi, I'm new to opencv and I'm trying to decode a byte array
From one side I'm sending I need to send a message in bytes format, and I'm using this code:**

image_bytes = cv2.imencode('.jpg', imageRGB)[1].tobytes()

**And from the receiving side, I'm am receiving a message with the following type: <class 'str'>
with this content:** /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBgYFBgYGBwkIBgcJBwYGCAsICQoK ...

**I tried the following:** (x['other']['contentBytes'] is where the bytes are)

nparr = np.fromstring(x['other']['contentBytes'], np.uint8)

**This returns a ( <class 'numpy.ndarray'> ) with the following shape: (40672,)**

**And when I try to**

```
            newFrame = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

**I get a <class 'NoneType'> type.**

Answer (score 0):

Your image is base64-encoded so you need to decode it first:

```
from base64 import b64decode
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Extract JPEG-encoded image from base64-encoded string
JPEG = b64decode(YOURDATA)

# Decode JPEG back into Numpy array
na = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(JPEG,dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```